# javascript TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

The line with problem

```
app.post('/' , (req ,res) => {   
const itemName = req.body.newItem;
const listName = req.body.list;

const item = new Item ({
    name: itemName
});

if(listName === 'Today'){
    item.save();
    res.redirect('/');
} else {
    Item.findOne({name: listName}, (err , result) => {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           result.item.push(item);
           result.save();  
       }
    });
    res.redirect('/' + listName);
}
});
```

This is my ejs form template

```
<form class="item" action="/" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Enter New Item" autocomplete="off"/>
  <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
</form>
```

When I run this code I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of null

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your error means that `result` is `null`. This happens when no document can be found that satisfies your query: `{name: listName}`. Check to make sure `listName` is what you think it is and whether or not it's in your collection.

Comment: could you add schema for `Item` Model